# a:hover doesn't match div height

Tags: html, css

This is a simple menu.

The problem is the `a:hover`. `a:hover` height must be the same of the mainmenu div, but now it is not. I tried to eliminate border and margin, but it didn't work

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87%;
  color: #333399;
}

#mainmenu {
  float: right;
  width: 680px;
  background-color: #BAB3D6;
  height: 23px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 23px;
}

#mainmenu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

#mainmenu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#mainmenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#mainmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #652D91;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #652D91;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why would you add a border of the same color?

Comment: @Julix I'dont want border

Comment: Then why would you have a border to begin with? - I took a wild guess at what you were trying to do (given that we're not seeing the rest of the page that might not be what you need in your context... I took out the fixed width and tiny font-size stuff, obviously feel free to add it back in if that was on purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- Set `a` as `display:block`, because `a` is an inline element.
- But your `li` which is currently `display:inline`needs to be an `inline-block` to hold the `a` as block level element

**Note:** I added `box-sizing` and use `padding` over `height/line-height`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87%;
  color: #339;
}

#mainmenu {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 680px;
  background-color: #BAB3D6;
}

#mainmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#mainmenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0
}

#mainmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #652D91;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I have modified some of the styles, please have a look at it. Hope this helps you!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87%;
  color: #333399;
}

#mainmenu {
  float: right;
  width: 680px;
  background-color: #BAB3D6;
  height: 23px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 23px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainmenu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainmenu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

#mainmenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#mainmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #652D91;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an opinionated answer changing more than what you asked for, but possibly for the better. Comment if you'd like anything changed.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333399;
}

#mainmenu {
  background-color: #BAB3D6;
}

#mainmenu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

#mainmenu li {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em 20px;
}

#mainmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #652D91;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```